# Uploading Different Versions App to the Apple App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, store

I have made several xcode versions for different sizes on the iphone (iphone4,iphone5, iphone6, iphone 6+, all which have different storyboards, due to the different sizes.  Due to the complexity of my app I wasnt able to do constraints.  Is there any way I can upload different versions of my app for different platforms on the app store?

For example, I want to upload my Xcode project for iphone4 to the app store, so that it is available for people with iphone4, and I want to upload my other Xcode project for iphone5 to the app store, so that it is available for those with iphone5.. and so on.

Thank you.  This is the first time I have ever uploaded an app to the Apple app store so any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: If you have multiple storyboards there should be a way of specifying which storyboard to use in the app delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion, for that problem you can use the new "size classes" in xcode 6. I recommend you watch the WWDC video and read this document. Doing that you only have to have one app.

https://www.codefellows.org/blog/size-classes-with-xcode-6-one-storyboard-for-all-sizes

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you use single app using adaptive layout for different version of device

In iTunes Connect you cannot create apps with same name,sku number,bundle-identifier .Those details should be unique . If you want to create different version apps for iPhone4 and iPhone5, then you have to create different apps in iTunes connect with different Names and Bundle identifier for different versions.
Please refer this before submitting  [Apple to reject any apps that don't use iPhone 5 displays as of May 21st](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/03/21/after-a-year-of-warnings-apple-will-no-longer-accept-any-apps-that-use-udids-as-of-may-1st/)

Comment: Also refer to 10.1: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-interface and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH54-SW1 ie. Use auto-layout and support all screen sizes in the one app